# Is $f(x,y)=x^2+y^4+xy$ convex?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I have the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^4+xy$ and I need to see if it is convex. So I take the hessian matrix: $$\nabla ^2f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 12y^2 \end{pmatrix}=A$$

And from here I find the principal minors: $$Det(A[[1],[1]])=2$$ $$Det(A[\{2\},\{2\}])=12y^2$$
$$Det(A[[2],[2]])=24y^2-1$$

And from those I see that they are not always non negative, because $y=0 \Rightarrow 24y^2-1=-1$

So therefore the function is not convex, is this correct?

Comment: This thing has, as far as I can see, *only two* leading principal minors, which is all we need: $\;A_{11}=2>0\;$ , and the determinant $\;24y^2-1\;$ , which will be non-negative $\;\iff |y|\ge\frac1{\sqrt{24}}\;$ , so over all it is not convex...but in some regions it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Note that for $(x,y)$ near the origin, the function looks like $x^2+xy=(x+y/2)^2-y^2/4$, whose graph is a saddle surface.